# How to export a psql database to a csv file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, export-to-csv

I would like to know how to "translate" the psql command line into a javascript function in my "queries.js" file so that when a user press a button it exports the database to the user downloads of my application !

here is the psql command line :

[psql command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWunj.png)

The js function i created but there is "a syntaxe error near or over tag_7z8eq73.csv" :

```
async function exportDatabase(req, res){
return db.any('COPY (SELECT adc_i, adc_v FROM tag_7z8eq73) TO "tag_7z8eq73.csv" DELIMITER "|" CSV HEADER')
    .then(rows => {
        // console.log(rows);
        res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

}

the route:

```
router.get('/export', db.exportDatabase);
```

the button function :

```
exportData(){
    fetch('http://192.168.1.51:3000/api/v1/export', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
            })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('database exported')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });

},
```

Thank you to those who will take the time to answer !

Comment: Tell us what happens exactly, "It doesn't work" is never helpful

Comment: If the delimiter is `|`, then it's not CSV. CSV is, by definition, comma separated.

Comment: @TheFool, `CSV` is effectively an alias for any separated value file. It long ago lost any hard association with commas.

Comment: Guessing the issue is `"tag_7z8eq73.csv"`. In Postgres double quotes are used for identifiers e.g. table, column names not strings. It should be `'tag_7z8eq73.csv'`.

Comment: Should have added that [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) runs as the server user so that user needs permissions on whatever location you write the file too. You can get around this by writing to `STDOUT`.

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver, thanks for your answers. Can you explain me what's STDOUT what is the use of writing on it ?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver How would you write the query ? Writing with solo quotes dosn't work as it is javascript

Comment: Re: Javascript: `var s = 'this is a "test"'  "this is a \"test\""` vs `var s2 = "this is a 'test'" "this is a 'test'"`.  Re: `STDOUT` see [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver But what am I supposed to expect writing on it ? Where can I find the datas, because nothing is happening actually.. here is the query : 'COPY tag_7z8eq73 TO STDOUT'

Comment: Read the link I sent on standard streams. My suggestion to use `STDOUT` was based on writing to a file failing because of permissions issues. Try writing to a file first once you have changed the quoting.

Comment: @AdrianKlayer From what I understand I am supposed to see my table loaded in the terminal of my code editor when I run "COPY tag_7z8eq73 TO STDOUT". I changed the quoting and tried to write to a file with "\copy tag_7z8eq73 TO 'C:\Users\New-rFid-Concept\Documents\BioTech_mathis\tag_7z8eq73.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER" But it tells me "a relative path is not allowed to use COPY to a file"